# Appending script dynamically fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to insert a script on a click or after setting some time out, (as shown below) and it does not append. However, if I remove the setTimeout function it does append. Same occurs with on click or any other event. Can somebody tell me why, and how I can accomplish this?

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    var parent = $('#panel');                   
    var element = $('<div></div>');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type','math/tex');
    script.textContent = 'e^{\\pi i} + 1 = 0';
    element.append(script); 

    parent.append(element);
}, 1500);
```

Comment: I would `console.log` the variables with and without the delay, and then compare them. Something about the document is changing (`#parent` is disappearing?).

Comment: @Chad Hedgcock I did console.log but the only thing I could see is that it is not appending the element, still don't know the reason!

Comment: Can you show your HTML, at least the `#panel`, in three different versions? 1. The raw source (`right click -> view source`). 2. `Right click -> inspect element` with the timeout. 3. `Right click -> inspect element` without the timeout. My guess is that some other script is changing the document, but that script relies on what you do in this script you've pasted. Adding a timeout switches the execution order which prevents this other mysterious script from working on `#panel` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**: if you're using MathJax, you need to tell MathJax to rescan the page for new latex tags after inserting this one after 1.5 seconds, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html usually you can get away with just running `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` which for you would mean:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var parent = $('#panel');                   
    var element = $('<div></div>');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type','math/tex');
    script.textContent = 'e^{\\pi i} + 1 = 0';
    element.append(script);
    parent.append(element);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
}, 1500);
```

**original answer:** it works here in my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aLe0jL3y/

I suspect you believe that once you append this script tag, that your latex library will automatically detect that it was inserted and parse it or something.

I don't know which library you're using for latex, but I'm guessing that your code works outside of the setTimeout because then it's being inserted *before* the latex library scans the page for math/tex script tags, whereas when you use a 1.5 second delay, the library would have already run, and so your script tag *is* being inserted but you don't see it because the latex library already ran by this point in time so it's not going to parse it.

I suggest making sure that the latex library uses is running *after* 1.5 seconds.